# Java Encryption Cast-256

Tags: java, encryption

I need to pass a CakePHP code to Java. One part of that is find a way to encrypt and decrypt some cards number.

In cakePHP use Cast-256 (http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAST-256) . Im finding a Cast-256's implementation on Java but im not geeting goods news.

I find in a post (https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1532311?tstart=4680) i should use that library org.bouncycastle. But i cant find a example of howto.

The question is:

`You know a way of encrypt and decrypt information with Cast-256 in Java?
Show me one example.`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the wiki article CAST-256 is also referred to as CAST6, which is supported by the bouncy castle provider.

maven;

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
  <version>140</version>
</dependency>
```

code;

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("CAST6");
```

If you don't know how to use block ciphers in java then have a bit of a google around. There's a lot of tutorials.

Comment: I make what you tell me, but i cant get me same Encryptation of PHP. When i encrypt the word "hola" (without quotes) with that key "CLp4j13gADa9AmRsqsXGJ" and i get "QUrYzMVlbx3OK6IKXWq1ng==" and i should get "w5nZSYEyA8HuPL5V0J29Yg==" !! I dont know why!

Comment: @JoseF - There are lots of questions on here asking why encryption doesn't match in PHP and Java. Have a search for some and if you can't solve your problem then ask another question.